# Why does a rotation transformation have 3 degrees of freedom?

Tags: computer-vision

I'm learning about computer vision and came across this point that my instructor made in the material regarding image transformations.

He claimed that rotation has 3 degrees of freedom, but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how that is. As far as I know, the rotation matrix is:

$$\mathbf{R} = \begin{bmatrix}\cos{(\theta)} & -\sin{(\theta)} \\ \sin{(\theta)} & \phantom{-}\cos{(\theta)}\end{bmatrix}$$

Doesn't this mean that we only have 1 degree of freedom, namely $\theta$?

I understand that a rigid (Euclidean) transformation (which is basically rotation + translation) has 3 degrees of freedom, but how does rotation have that?

I've also checked the [Wikipedia page for rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_(mathematics)) but it seems that rotation has 3 degrees of freedom when in $\mathbb{R}^3$. I also checked the [Wikipedia page for the rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) but it doesn't mention anything about degrees of freedom.

Comment: You can also pick the origin about which to rotate (should be 2 coordinates)

Comment: Wouldn't that also be a $\mathbb{R}^3$ case though?

Answer (score 2):

Rotation in 2d about a fixed point has only 1 degree of freedom, while in 3d has 3 degrees of freedom. In general, in n dimensions you have $\frac{1}{2}n(n−1)$ degrees of freedom. I think the important point here is that when usually talking, we assume the origin point is fixed. You should clear this up with your instructor.